# Heelp me for using viewmodel with radio group,when i rotate it was unchecked

Tags: radio-button, viewmodel, android-viewmodel, radio-group

**FirstPage.java**

'viewModel = new ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(PagesVM.class);

```
    radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener((group, checkedId) -> {

        checkedId = group.getCheckedRadioButtonId();


        invisibleBtn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            switch (checkedId) {
                case 0:

                case 1:
                case 2:

                case 3:

                    count += 0;
                    break;

                case 4:
                    count += 1;
                    break;


            }


        viewModel.getSelectedValue().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(),check -> {


            radioGroup.setSelected(check);

        });

    });'
```

**FirstPageVm.java**

public class PagesVM extends ViewModel {

```
MutableLiveData<Boolean> setItem=new MutableLiveData<Boolean>();


LiveData<Boolean> getSelectedValue(){
    return setItem;
}
RadioGroup radioGroup;
public void slectItem(){

    setItem.setValue(radioGroup.isSelected());
}
```

}

**Error**

at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2307)

```
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8512)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1130)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.widget.RadioGroup.isSelected()' on a null object reference

    at mening.dasturim.mytest.ui.pages.PagesVM.slectItem(PagesVM.java:21)
    at mening.dasturim.mytest.ui.pages.FirstPage.onDestroy(FirstPage.java:115)
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performDestroy(Fragment.java:3219)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.destroy(FragmentStateManager.java:774)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:350)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStore.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStore.java:112)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1647)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3128)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchDestroy(FragmentManager.java:3107)
```

android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:5587)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:5647) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:5939) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:5869) 
at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityRelaunchItem.execute(ActivityRelaunchItem.java:69) 
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2307) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8512) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1130) 
2021-08-14 02:21:59.001 4226-4548/? E/BufferQueueProducer: com.samsung.android.app.cocktailbarservice/com.samsung.android.app.cocktailbarservice.CocktailBarService$_11743#0 disconnect: not connected (req=1)
2021-08-14 02:21:59.011 4900-4900/? E/ndroid.systemu: Invalid ID 0x00000000.

Comment: help me solve this logic

Answer (score 0):

**you should omit**

RadioGroup radioGroup;
public void slectItem(){

```
setItem.setValue(radioGroup.isSelected());
```

}

and run again